# How to expand my Ubuntu partition?

Tags: 16.10, partitioning

First of all, please take a look at the picture below.

I am using Ubuntu 16.10 alongside Windows 10. Now I want to separate 15GB from /dev/sda6 and add it to the Ubuntu partition (/dev/sda9). How should I do it?

[image: Gparted]

Answer (score 0):

The best approach will be to first reduce the sda6 partition by 15 GB from Windows (though gparted can reduce a windows partition, it's oftenbetter to use windows tools for windows stuff). Then boot on live usb:

- In gparted drag sda8 left into the free space,
- then sda9 left in the same way.
- Choose Execute to implement the changes.
- Last, expand sda9 by dragging the right border right into the now
  free space,
- Execute again.

Though all above should be safe operations, it never hurts to make a backup before messing with partitions.